# Trying to overload operator++, cannot call member function without object

Tags: c++, iterator, overloading, operator-keyword

Sorry if the formatting is a bit off, I'm new here. I also tried searching for solutions but I couldn't find one that worked.

I'm trying to create an iterator for a binary search tree class. Very roughly, my code looks like

```
template<class Key, class Value>
class BST {
  protected:
    //stuff
  public:
    //stuff
    class iterator {
      public:
        //member functions
        iterator& operator++() {
          //gets next node
        }
    }
}
```

So in my main function, I create an iterator with

```
BST<string, int>::iterator it = bst.begin()
```

and it works. I can access the node using the iterator. But on the next line when I try to

```
it++;
```

I get compiler errors saying that I "cannot call member function ... without object". I don't understand why not? If I'm calling operator++ on 'it', shouldn't it just operate on 'it'?

Comment: The operator that you've overloaded is pre-incrementation use: `iterator& operator++(int)` for post-incrementation.

Answer (score 4):

Postfix increment operator overloading requires a dummy `int` argumet in it's signature - to distringuish it from prefix incerement. Like so:

```
   iterator operator++(int ) {
      //gets next node
    }
```

You also usually return a value from postfix increment, not a reference, since you are expected to return pre-incremented object.